# webmatrix - Reply-To webmail.send header

Tags: razor, webmatrix, webmail

Anyone know how to do the following in C#?

```
additionalHeaders.Add("Reply-To: test@test.com");
```

I need to insert it into the following code:

```
WebMail.Send(to: customerEmail,
        subject: "Booking enquiry from - " + customerEmail,
        body: customerRequest
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using:

```
var header = new[]{"Reply-To:test@hotmail.com"};
WebMail.Send(to: customerEmail,
        subject: "Booking enquiry from - " + customerEmail,
        body: customerRequest,
        additionalHeaders: header
    );
```